# Interfacing 9-Axes Motion Shield with RPi and WiFi Shield

Tags: sensors, wifi, ethernet

I recently purchased the [Arduino 9-Axes Motion Shield](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/5-arduino-shields/arduino-9-axes-motion-shield). I have two questions:

Q1. The official Arduino page says that the shield doesn't have any external power source and can only be powered up by stacking on top of an Arduino board. How can I use this shield with a Raspberry Pi?

Q2. A page [here](http://www.mouser.in/new/arduino/arduino-9-axes/) shows that it has support for the Ethernet Shield but doesn't mention WiFi shield anywhere. Does this mean that I cannot use my WiFi shield with it? I plan to stack the 9-axes shield on top of the WiFi shield which in turn is stacked over Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. The official Arduino page says that the shield doesn't have any external power source and can only be powered up by stacking on top of an Arduino board. How can I use this shield with a Raspberry Pi?

By providing the right power to the right pins.

> Q2. A page here shows that it has support for the Ethernet Shield but doesn't mention WiFi shield anywhere. Does this mean that I cannot use my WiFi shield with it? I plan to stack the 9-axes shield on top of the WiFi shield which in turn is stacked over Arduino Uno.

No, it says it is compatible with the [*Arduino Ethernet*](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) which is not a shield, it is an Arduino.

What other shields you can use it with depends on what pins those other shields use.  Look at the schematics. Read the manuals. Do some leg-work.